# Where is the arp_cleanup_interval variable in Solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, arp, solaris-10, solaris-11

In Solaris 10 I can configure (and audit) the arp_cleanup_interval variable using the following command:

```
$ ndd -get /dev/arp arp_cleanup_interval
300000
```

In Solaris 11 (Express and Release) the same command returns an "Unknown property" error:

```
$ ndd -get /dev/arp arp_cleanup_interval
operation failed: Unknown property
```

Does anyone know if this variable has changed, or been removed from Solaris 11?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they were removed, by the IP Datapath Refactoring project described in [this mail thread from the architecture review](http://arc.opensolaris.org/caselog/PSARC/2009/331/mail).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command:

```
 ndd /dev/arp \?
```

to get a list of all the parameters that are supported.  BTW, this information is contained in the man page for ndd.